# Android. How to depends on ids of included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints

I have first layout I want to include

```
// first_layout.xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFirstLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First layout text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I have second layout, where first will be included

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include layout="@layout/first_layout"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSecondLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text of second layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvFirstLayout"/> // THIS IS THE QUESTION

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now the problem is use first textView as constraint to second textView. Any resolves of this ?

Comment: Why not make it's top constraint be the layout itself?

Answer (score -1):

Give `height`, `width` and `id` to the `<include>` tag and then you can set the constraints.

Answer (score -1):

You can set id for the include tag

```
<include android:id="@+id/include" 
         layout="@layout/first_layout"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSecondLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text of second layout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include"/> // Note you can reference include tag with id
```

and then reference the include tag with its id.

Comment: I need to constraint to fiirstTextView, not to layout

Comment: Then you might go to set the constraints programmatically. Get a reference to the include tag and then access the inner tvSecondLayout set the constraints to its id and it might work. I haven't tried it before so I am not sure its going to work.

Comment: Yeah, I know this way. Thank you. But it could be great do this from xml file.

Comment: If tvSecondLayout is part of the included layout then you can simply make it in the included layout. If its sometimes exist and sometimes don't you can include it and add binding variable to define whether you should show it or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
<include layout="@layout/first_layout"
        android:id="@+id/include"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now you are able to set the constraints.

Comment: I need to constraint to fiirstTextView, not to layout